# AWS Lambda API blocked by CORS policy

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, cors, serverless-framework

I have an API in AWS Lambda and when I try to call it I get an error related to the CORS policy although I think I'm configuring the CORS right.

I have an API writen in Python in AWS Lambda, which I deployed with Serverless Framework. Though when I fetch the API from the frontend it gets errors related to the CORS configuration.

"Access to fetch at 'https://0vdu10a3e6.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/init' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

After trying some fixes I got to this but I still get the error

```
def init(event, context):
       # removed most of the code
           return {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Credentials",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET",
                    'Content-Type': "application/json"
                },
                "body": json.dumps(response)
            }
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11.2023.09.12.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY Models/best.pt /app
COPY AcharyaMeasuringPrototype.py /app
COPY Utlis.py /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip cache purge
RUN pip install 'ultralytics[yolo]~=8.0.147'
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "AcharyaMeasuringPrototype.init" ]
```

This is my serverless.yaml:

```
service: acharya-ml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload"
            - "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
            - "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy"
          Resource:
            !Join 
              - ':'
              - - 'arn:aws:ecr'
                - Ref: AWS::Region
                - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                - 'repository/*'
plugins:
# - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

functions:
  main:
    image: 550512796301.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/acharya-prototype-ml:latest
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /init 
          method: POST
```

This is how I fetch:

```
const res = await fetch("https://hinjggqsg4.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/init", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      });
```

I also don't get any log in Lambda.
If anyone could help I'd be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentions 'preflight'.
This is usually associated to the HTTP OPTIONS method.
Try to return:

```
def init(event, context):
       # removed most of the code
           return {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Credentials",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS",
                    'Content-Type': "application/json"
                },
                "body": json.dumps(response)
            }
```